# AFNetwork + JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary, afnetworking

This is my first time using AFNetwork and before I was using ASIHTTP request, which I could not re-use my code, but anyway, I am having trouble with the JSON extract and I cannot seems to figure out why, so I hope someone could show me the light

This is the code

```
[httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
[httpClient postPath:@"" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSString *responseStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *results = (NSDictionary *) responseStr;
    NSArray *pets = [results objectForKey:@"animals"];
```

And this is the JSON

```
   {
  "animals" : [
  {
     "type" : "cat",
     "weight" : "2lbs"      
},
  {
     "type" : "cat",
     "weight" : "15oz"
  }
   ]
}
```

Somehow I am always getting -[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7355ab0' at parsing the NSArray from the dictionary, which I have no trouble before... did I missed anything?   >,<

After trying and trying.........

Thank you all for taking the time to answer my question. I have no idea why it didn't work, but I turn out using NSJSONSerialization and now the array works perfectly.

```
[httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
[httpClient postPath:@"" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
NSError*error;
    NSDictionary *results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSArray *pets = [results objectForKey:@"animals"];
```

Comment: You can't cast an `NSString` into an `NSDictionary`...

Comment: @Amar there is no need to use NSJSONSerialization with AFNetworking.

Comment: @VaibhavGautam Yup. I guess I did not read correctly.

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://samwize.com/2012/10/25/simple-get-post-afnetworking/) was very useful for me to send and get JSON objects from my server.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Or using `+ (instancetype)JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)urlRequest success:(void ( ^ ) ( NSURLRequest *request , NSHTTPURLResponse *response , id JSON ))success failure:(void ( ^ ) ( NSURLRequest *request , NSHTTPURLResponse *response , NSError *error , id JSON ))failure` will return you directly a JSON object in the success block

Comment: thanks, I have the post and response fine until the  NSArray *pets = [results objectForKey:@"animals"];  line.

Comment: I've never tried, but I'm pretty sure that you can't cast a `NSDictionary` from a `NSString`

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue long time back, there is a small workaround for the same

in AFJSONRequestOperation go to method responseJSON and change

```
self.responseJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:self.JSONReadingOptions error:&error];
```

to this

```
self.responseJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

Comment: yep, everything works ok up until the parsing the array. the dictionary is fine from NSLog